# Output CSV to Excel table

Tags: excel, csv

I have a `Sub` that reads lines from a CSV and outputs the data in to an Excel table.  Or at least it's supposed to...

I first clear the table and delete all rows using this function, although I notice that the first data row always remains.

```
Sub ClearTableData(ByRef Table As ListObject)

    On Error Resume Next

    Table.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, 0).Resize( _
        Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, _
        Table.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Rows.Delete

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Now I attempt to repopulate the table, but things are not quite right.  The first row from the CSV is correctly inserted in to row 1 of the table, but after that all rows from the CSV are inserted underneith the table, one row after the other.

I've inserted a screenshot after the code below to show what is happening.  How can I correctly output the CSV data in to the table?

```
Sub UpdateTableData(ByRef Table As ListObject, ByVal resultsFileName As String)

    Dim BackupResults As Integer    ' Dummy to loop through the backup results file
    Dim thisLine As String          ' The current line being read from the backup results file
    Dim newRow As ListRow           ' The new table row to use

    BackupResults = FreeFile()
    Open resultsFileName For Input As #BackupResults    ' Open the backup results file

    While Not EOF(BackupResults)

        Line Input #BackupResults, thisLine     ' Grab the current line from '#BackupResults'

        Set newRow = Table.ListRows.Add         ' Add a new table row

        Dim rowNum As Integer
        rowNum = Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count ' Set the row number to output this line to

        Dim parts() As String
        parts = Split(thisLine, ",")            ' Split 'thisLine' into invidual parts

        Dim part As Variant
        Dim colNum As Integer: colNum = 1
        For Each part In parts                  ' Loop through all 'parts' and output it to the correct table column

            If Trim(part) <> "" Then

                newRow.Range.Cells(rowNum, colNum).Value = Trim(part)   ' Output the 'part' to its cell
                colNum = colNum + 1

            End If

        Next

    Wend

    Close #BackupResults    ' Close the backup results file

    Set newRow = Nothing    ' Destroy the 'newRow' object

End Sub
```

[image: What is currently happening]

Comment: Why don't you use the standard Excel Data ->Import From Text feature? Also, Range.ClearContents could be handy (instead of Rows.Delete).

Comment: You can't import data in to a Table, so rather than just deleting data rows I'd have to create a new table with the data each time, which seems like a bigger job.  Correct me if I'm wrong though...

Comment: Typically importing a CSV files into Excel is easy. Even without using any VBA you can click on the CSV file and select Open With Excel option to get the data into Excel Worksheet. And ,you can also perform Text File import via VBA using Import spec if necessary (but most likely it is not in case of CSV). Use Macro recorder to build a proto, then polish the Sub. Best regards,

Comment: The `newRow` in your code is *one* new empty row already. So the `rowNum` is not necessary. Try `newRow.Range.Cells(1, colNum).Value = Trim(part)   ' Output the 'part' to its cell`.

Comment: @AlexBell - Yes it's simple to do, but it doesn't serve my needs.  For example, the table I wish to use is named and several cells make reference to the table to present certain data to the user.  Using the import data method for my scarario would just make things harder.

Comment: @AxelRichter - Thank you, that was exactly the problem so my code is now working.  Please post as an answer and I will accept :)

Comment: Then you have to edit your question adding that important clarification. It's kinda misleading, i.e. "Output CSV to Excel table" - just a single VBA statement can do the job as shown in my answer. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose starting with a Table with only headings, the first `Set newRow = Table.ListRows.Add` will add a new empty row into the Table. The `rowNum = Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count`then will be 1. So `newRow.Range.Cells(rowNum, colNum).Value = Trim(part)` will put the data into row 1 of the `newRow`. Row 1 ist the `newRow` itself.

The second `Set newRow = Table.ListRows.Add` will again add a new empty row into the Table. The `rowNum = Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count`then will be 2. So `newRow.Range.Cells(rowNum, colNum).Value = Trim(part)` will put the data into row 2 of the `newRow`. This is one row below the `newRow`. This will further be the case with the third, the fourth, the nth occurance of `Set newRow = Table.ListRows.Add`.

So the result will be what you had seen. Row 1 correct, then n new added Rows and the data below of them.

The `newRow` in your code is one new empty row already. So the `rowNum` is not necessary.

```
newRow.Range.Cells(1, colNum).Value = Trim(part)
```

will ever put your data into the colNum of the first row into the `Range` of your `newRow`, which is the `newRow` itself.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I misunderstood the use of `Cells()`, but this clears things up nicely.